# Convert flat array of string into associative array

Tags: php

I want to convert this array of string;

```
$arList = ["the","quick","brown","fox"];
```

into this format.

```
[
   "the" => [
        "quick" => [
            "brown" => []
        ]
   ]
]
```

Sorry for not posting some code.

here is what I tried,

```
<?php

$arList = ["the","quick","brown","fox"];

$newList = [];
$pointer = $newList;
foreach($arList as $item) {
    $pointer[$item] = [];
    $pointer = &$newList[$item];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: what happened to the `fox`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from the net using the following code;

```
$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($arList), function($prevArray, $key){
    return $prevArray ? [$key => $prevArray] : [$key];
}, null);
```